# Running JNA's Native.loadLibrary on android

Tags: android, jna

I'm trying to load a dll library during run time in my android project. I was able to do this in a regular java project using `Native.loadLibrary("C:\path_to_my_file\my_dll.dll", MYLIB.class)` but I can't run the same thing on android. I've seen that there is an option to run JNA on android in their documentation, but maybe I'm diong it wrong.

I've placed the `my_dll.dll` file in the `assets` folder of the android project but now I don't know what should I place as the first parameter in the `Native.loadLibrary` method.

Comment: the "dll" should be compiled for android (linux) and your dll is prolly for windows ...

Comment: the dll ins't compiled for windows

Comment: You should take a look at "Android Native Development Kit Cookbook". There is a section about porting existing c/c++ projects to Android native libs.

Comment: so why it calls my_dll.dll not my_dll.so? it have to be also builded for proper CPU type arm/mips/x86 and provided inside apk file ...

Comment: @Selvin sorry you're right, can I instead load the .h and .c files instead? Still where should I place them in the android project and how do I access them?

Comment: get android NDK and run first sample :)